# WINDOW clause in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

Is it possible to declare a WINDOW once in Snowflake?
For example, I want to have several columns that use a single window. And I don't want to repeat few times OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...).
Like this simple example:

```
SELECT
  c1
  ,c2
 ,first_value(value) OVER  my_win as fval
 ,last_value(value) OVER my_win as lval
 ,.... OVER  my_win as example1 
 ,...  OVER  my_win as  example2
 ,...  OVER my_win as example3
FROM my_table
WINDOW my_win AS (PARTITION BY c1 ORDER BY c2);
```

I looked for the answer in the Snowflake documentation but could not find it.

I want to have clear DRY query.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know it's not possible,

I asked this very same question in December 2018 on [Snowflake forum](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008fZVLZSA4/is-there-a-way-to-reuse-a-partition-by-clause-) and the consensus back then it's that they don't have the `WINDOW window_name AS (window_definition)` functionality that is present in PostgreSQL (see [1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html), [2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) and [3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) ).

I registered long time ago in [Snowflake Ideas](https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas) the "Suppor syntax for SELECT func1() OVER(w), func2() OVER(w) ... WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY xxx ORDER BY yyyy)", you can search in Snowflake Ideas for it and vote for it.

Right now you will need to repeat the `OVER (PARTITION BY xxxxx)` for each window function.

It's a shame that Snowflake does not support this named window clauses because as the  PostgreSQL documentation [1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) states:

> When a query involves multiple window functions, it is possible to write out each one with a separate OVER clause, but **this is duplicative and error-prone if the same windowing behavior is wanted for several functions**. Instead, each windowing behavior can be named in a WINDOW clause and then referenced in OVER.